# If we have SPO, can we then do hybrid as well?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hybrid-solution

I know that in general it's possible to move from in-house SharePoint to SharePoint Online, or even to a Hybrid configuration; but what about the other way around?

**Can we create a SharePoint Hybrid configuration if we have SharePoint Online?**

---

<sup>This has come about from a recent discussion I've had with our IT Security officer who has mentioned that certain departments must store there content "in-house", and I suggested Hybrid as a solution, so that the users can still enjoy the SharePoint interface they're used to, but the content never leaves our space.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

That's not how hybrid functions. The content of hybrid is always separated. In certain modes, hybrid allows you to search both SPO and SharePoint on-prem, but you must use one or the other interface to interact with that content (e.g. navigating to the Document Library will be SPO for SPO content, SharePoint on-prem for SharePoint on-prem content).

Comment: That's the setup I'm thinking of (I may not have explained it properly).

Comment: We'd be using two different interfaces, that's true (one SPO and one On-prem), however, it will both be SharePOint, so it will be familiar.

Comment: You're correct, it will be familiar (more so if you use SharePoint 2016 as the SuiteNav looks nearly the same) as long as you're using the Classic List experience in SPO.